# What is the script equivalent dataLayer to gtagjs in google analytics?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-analytics

I have this script from google analytics:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
 'userId' : '123456'
})
window.dataLayer.push({
 'event' : 'login',
})
```

Cause I'm using vue, I want to insert this script by [vue-gtag](https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/methods/events) way.

So vue-gtag uses [gtagjs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events). And according to the docs I should do it as:

gtag('event', 'login');

But what about `userId`? where I put this code? how to convert the above script to `gtagjs` code?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you can set ID and other configuration options during the registration of the vue-gtag module. Example taken and modified from the vue-gtag docs.

```
Vue.use(VueGtag, {
  config: { userId: '123456' },
});
```

Instead of using `gtag('event', 'login')`, you use the appropriate method exposed on this.$gtag: `this.$gtag.event('login')`.

You can similarly use the config method `this.$gtag.config({ userId: '123456'})` to set your credentials later, if you'd want.

Comment: Can I do it dynamically when the user click on the login button? (push method)

Comment: I'm dealing with the same thing here. I don't think that the suggested approach is ideal. Typically, the gtag property should be defined once in App.vue and then push custom events to tag manager in a similar way to `window.dataLayer.push`.

Comment: That's what @Excalibaard said, the equivalent of `window.dataLayer.push()`, using _vue-gtag_ library is calling `this.$gtag.event('foo')`